# Can DTO in MVC asp.net load data by itself

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Consider that I have DTO for view. At domain layer we have the entity . We can use automapper to fill the DTO from entity. But do we need to perform all these at application service class or can we have method at Model which can be called by Controller to perform this process. I need to know the class structure for MVC

Comment: I like to overload the constructor of my ViewModel to take in my Entity object and do the mapping there.

Comment: DTOs/entities/viewmodels are just classes. they can contain methods to do whatever you want just like any other class. You can put a method on it to convert it to another object type, you can have a constructor that takes in one object type and builds a different one, or you can use a tool like automapper. if you're already using automapper, I'd suggest on continuing to use it. there's no reason to introduces another pattern in your application for doing the same thing. Whatever you do, i strongly suggest to pick one and stick with it

Answer (score 1):

Regarding adding the mapping methods to Models, I would disagree and suggest to keep the Entity classes as simple as possible (POCO). I personally prefer to do the mapping either at Application Service Layer or in ViewModels.